# Tribond: what do these three have in common?

Tags: wordplay, tribond

I don't know if anybody has played the game Tribond, but here's how it works: three words are given, and the player has to figure out what they have in common. Example: "What do Earth, Pie, and Bread all have in common?"  Answer: "They all have crusts". Answers ARE permitted to rely on homophones, an example (not a very good one), being "What do Apple, Cherry, and 3.14159..." have in common? Answer: "They're all pie/pi" (Apple Pie, Cherry Pie, and pi)! So, here are two Tribond puzzles I've come up with (hopefully they take more than five seconds to solve):

What do these three have in common:

> Discussions, Sewing machines, screws?
>
> Printers, Airplanes, New York?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This would be

> All have threads
>  Screws are threaded, discussions in forums have threads and sewing machines use thread to sew.

And

> All have jets.
>  Printers have ink jets, airplanes have jet engines and The New York Jets are a sports franchise.

Comment: That was quick! I can't accept for 11 minutes but I will then.

Comment: They are also finite :-)

Comment: @CarlLöndahl you are saying it only bcz you haven't heard my conversations with my friends... Discussions are infinite

Comment: @manshu haha, ok!

Comment: I was rushing to make your 5 second deadline but I think I typed too slowly. :)

Comment: @CarlLöndahl And they have a physical existence, and are spelled with letters. Does this make the question too broad ? :)

Comment: @RichardRoe Nah, its fine . Upvoted :-)